# DefaultTableModel make cell not editable JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, overriding, defaulttablemodel

I have an JAVA project and want to make my JTable with a DefaultTableModel non-editable. I know a work-around to do this, called:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...){  
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){  
    return false;  
  }  
};
```

Like said: i dont like this. This is not according the rules of my school training.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe is there a good way. I hope so!

Comment: What rules were your school training?

Comment: the school says that it's not supossed to be like the code given.

Comment: is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not subclass the JTable itself, but the table model:

```
DefaultTableModel myModel = new DefaultTableModel(...) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or even better, don't use a DefaultTableModel, and use an AbstractTableModel that directly gets the information in your business objects rather than copying all the information from the business objects to Vectors.

Answer (score 2):

select Jtable , and don't forget to create  table model (DefaultTableModel TableModel)

```
JTable table_1 = new JTable (TableModel){public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int column)  
        {switch(column){             
           case 4:  // select the cell you want make it not editable 
             return false;  
         default: return true;}  
        }};
```